# Azure Webapp scaling issue

Tags: azure, scaling, autoscaling, azure-webapps

Facing issue 'The scale out operation for the plan 'ExtraaEdge-WebApp-Win-Plan' failed:  You have exceeded the maximum amount of scale changes within the past hour(86 changes and limit is 40). Please retry later' on Auto scale of Azure webapp.

Comment: I am not sure what the actual question is. You need to adjust your scaling settings. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/scaling-web-app-faq#i-m-unable-to-scale-up-scale-down-the-app-service-plan-due-to-the--you-have-exceeded-the-maximum-amount-of-scale-changes-within-the-past-hour--xx-changes-and-limit-is-xx---error--what-should-i-do--

Comment: So We are not able scale out - manually, automatically for last 12 hours. Its displaying above error. Before that we had scaled down our resources to save cost but didnt knew it will take more than 12 hours for acquiring new instance.

Comment: Have you checked the scaling settings? As it seems the scaling settings are way too aggressive. Logs might show you why it scaled so many times.

Comment: yes , I have checked same also. As shared we have kept it at 1 instance last 6 hours but still facing same error. Is it on Per app service plan/Per hour?

Comment: That I don't know. If the logs do not show any scaling operations and yet you get this error I would open a support ticket.

Comment: Yes please that will be helpful, As we are still  facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

> The scale out operation for the plan 'ExtraaEdge-WebApp-Win-Plan' failed: You have exceeded the maximum amount of scale changes within the past hour(86 changes and limit is 40). Please retry later

- This error could be because the autoscaling rules might be too aggressive or spike in traffic.
- This error is related to the scale sets instances. It takes time to acquire new instances based on multiple factors like size, region, and the availability of resources.
- Wait for some time and try scaling out again later.
- Check if you have configured auto scaling rules for the plan correctly.

As mentioned in the *[MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/scaling-web-app-faq#i-m-unable-to-scale-up-scale-down-the-app-service-plan-due-to-the--you-have-exceeded-the-maximum-amount-of-scale-changes-within-the-past-hour--xx-changes-and-limit-is-xx---error--what-should-i-do--)*:

- Every time, a new instance is released during a scale-down operation, the instance will be rebooted to make sure the next plan can get a clean instance.
- When you perform too many scaling operations, instance reboots can cause performance issues for other App Services. So, there is a mechanism(throttling) which prevents from executing scaling operations more than the limit.

Track the current Auto Scale status of your resource in *Portal=>Monitor*.

For each resource, we can see current instance count and the Autoscale status as shown below:

[image]

- Not configured: autoscale is not yet enabled for that particular resource.
- Enabled: Enabled autoscale for the resource.
- Disabled: autoscale is disabled for the resource.

There is already an issue raised in [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/97530). you can comment your issue and track the same.